# Как работает бинарное дерево для строк

Tags: c++

Например, взяв std::map, где все элементы упорядочены, делать вставку где - ключ int, тогда все понятно, как оно будет работать, но а как оно будет работать, если тип **std::string** например, либо **std::vector**.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, int> a;
    

    a.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("String", 6));
    a.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("NotString", 3));
    a.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("MaybeString", 2));
    a.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("Onemorestring", 5));


    for (auto ab : a)
    {
        std::cout << ab.second;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем принципиальное отличие? Просто свой вариант отношения "меньше", только и всего. Например, лексикографический...

Comment: @Harry То есть, это как-то связано с расположением букв в алфавите?

Comment: Это как то связано с кодовыми таблицами символов (прим ascii \ utf8 \..... )

Comment: По умолчанию да, но можно написать и свой компаратор...

Comment: @Harry ну я вот и имел ввиду по умолчанию

Comment: Такие вопросы лучше не здесь задавать, а открыть справку и посмотреть, как работает `operator<` у класса `string`. А там написано `operator< - lexicographically compares two strings`.